# Blackberry: Dowloading images in custom field slows VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry

Here is the paint method of my custom field:

```
   protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

            new downloadImage();
            Bitmap img =  downloadImage.connectServerForImage(this.poster);


            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 100, 150, img, LEFT, TOP);
     }
```

Here is the connectServerForImage method:

```
public static Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {

          HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
          DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
          InputStream httpInput = null;
          int rc;

          Bitmap bitmp = null;
          try {
           httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
           rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
           if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
           }
           httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
           InputStream inp = httpInput;
           byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
           EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
           return hai.getBitmap();

          } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" + ex.getMessage());
          } finally {
           try {
            if (httpInput != null)
             httpInput.close();
            if (httpDataOutput != null)
             httpDataOutput.close();
            if (httpConnection != null)
             httpConnection.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

           }
          }
          return bitmp;
         }
```

I'm putting multiple instances of my custom field into a verticalfieldmanager, but the images slows the scrolling down. It seems as if every time I scroll it runs the paint method again even though the image has already been downloaded.

I'm thinking I will need to download the images in another thread? Someone lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. You must start any HTTP interaction in a separate thread (no blocking call).
> 2. To avoid downloading same image multiple times cache already downloaded image. You can use image download URL as image tag to store
>      them.
> 3. Every time there is a event on screen, paint method will be called. So don't start download an image if it is already downloaded.

Comment: Addition for the 3 - don't start download if it's already started.

Comment: thanks i made another thread for downloading. Any examples on how to implement the suggestions you've made?